# How to convert unix timestamp (milliseconds) and timezone in R?

Tags: r, datetime, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have data which has two columns `time` and `timezone` that have the timestamp of events. Examples are:

```
time               timezone
1433848856453      10800000
```

It seems like the timestamp has fractional seconds in the information as well. I don't understand the timezone format but it must be an equivalent unix format. I need to preserve the fractional seconds as well. How do I go from that to something like in R?

```
2015-01-01 13:34:56.45 UTC
```

Note: This human readable date is not the actual converted values of the unix timestamp shown.

Comment: `timezone` column has also negative values?. Anyway I think Joshua had a very good idea about how to interpret `timezone`; milliseconds + or - the hour due to time zones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `timezone` column is the timezone offset, in milliseconds. I assume that means the timezone column will adjust for daylight saving time manually

So you should add the `time` and `timezone` columns before converting to `POSIXct`. You should also set the `tz` to `"UTC"` so no DST adjustments will be made to your `POSIXct` object.

```
R> time <- 1433848856453
R> timezone <- 10800000
R> options(digits.secs=3)
R> .POSIXct((time+timezone)/1000, tz="UTC")
[1] "2015-06-09 14:20:56.453 UTC"
```

Comment: I'm no expert in R but i'm a bit puzzled, why does the timezone have to go in... The Unix timestamp is already enough information to define a moment. Is there something about these R functions that can't take into account DST adjustments?

Comment: @Teo: The problem is that the timezone offset doesn't define a timezone, so there's no way for R to know when DST adjustments occur (there are several timezones that are UTC+3 and they may or may not have different DST rules). That's why I said I assume the timezone column will reflect DST adjustments.

Comment: The timezone offset may not define a timezone but there should be a timezone defined in the locale/time settings of the machine. For example Javascript knows about DST which may or may not occur in the local timezone (as far as i know & tested). So getting a Date object in Javascript will account for DST even if it's 5 years ago and should convert to UTC accordingly.. I was just curious if R is capable of this too. What's not so nice IMO is if you really need to account for specific timezones (explicitly) to convert a Unix timestamp to a UTC time :) - i assume UTC was never affected by DST

Comment: @Teo: Yes, there is (usually) a timezone defined by the OS, and R tries to use that. I adjusted the Unix timestamp for the timezone offset and set the POSIXct object's timezone to UTC so it would represent the local time where it was measured, rather than *my* local time when it was measured at UTC+3.  You could do `.POSIXct(time)` to get the Unix time in your local time, but I'm not sure which the OP would prefer.

Comment: Ok, so i guess you're saying UTC is actually not the timezone of the displayed time and it's UTC+[the given offset] instead. If that's the case i understand.. though maybe it's a bit misleading to not also show "+offset" in the answer. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be right for you.

```
aa <- 1433848856453
as.POSIXct(aa/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2015-06-09 13:20:56.453 CEST"
```

#### Edit

Now I've realized that my code is not reproducible, because of my personal settings, but this can fix it and let you achieve the goal.

```
options(digits.secs=6)
```