# zoo to xts, modifying index

Tags: r, csv, xts, zoo

**Question:** How to put specified zoo structure into xts?

**Info:**

Import from csv gives zoo object, where time is unix timestamp (with ms).

```
              V2      V3
1441711943070 1.11472 1.11476
1441711946545 1.11472 1.11477
1441711946784 1.11472 1.11476
...
```

Trying to get that into xts fails.

```
xtsible(data)
[1] FALSE

xts <- as.xts(data)
Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency,  : 
order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

Temporarily i solved the problem by changing csv structure and read with POSIXct, but i want to keep timestamps for ease of data saving.

**Idea:** Can I re-parse epoch index into time-based structure or is there a better solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050756/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-milliseconds-and-timezone-in-r

Comment: @tonytonov Thank you, that worked, then just redoing the index with `index(data) <- .POSIXct((index(data)+timezone)/1000, tz="UTC")`

Comment: Glad that helped! I will flag as a duplicate then.