# R Milliseconds to DateTime Conversion

Tags: r

I have refered all the posts related to conversion of milliseconds to date time in R, however, I am quite stuck and unable to proceed, I am unable to find where I am going wrong or am missing something, some help would be appreciated.

```
library(anytime);
msValue=1483383963966L;
anytime(msValue);
as.POSIXlt(msValue, origin="1970-01-01");
as.POSIXct(msValue, origin="1970-01-01");
```

I am trying to convert 1483383963966 milliseconds (which corresponds to Mon Jan 02 2017 19:06:03) in R, I am getting the below output:

```
> anytime(msValue);
[1] "48976-07-26 02:36:06 IST"
> as.POSIXlt(msValue, origin="1970-01-01");
[1] "48976-07-26 02:36:06 IST"
> as.POSIXct(msValue, origin="1970-01-01");
[1] "48976-07-26 02:36:06 IST"
```

Am I missing something, it is not giving the expected output

Comment: you need seconds, alas `as.POSIXct(msValue / 1000, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31050756

Comment: Yes, now the output is coming as [1] "2017-01-03 00:36:03 IST", which is correct @mtoto. I definitely missed the post, mentioned by  RHertel