# Date conversion in R number to date

Tags: r, date

I have this number 13132800000 and i know that is a birthdate "06/02/1970" or "02 june 1970".

How can i convert this number to this date in R

I have no idea of what kind of date is that

With

```
Library(zoo)
as.Date(person$birthDate)
[1] "-5877641-06-23"
```

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050756/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-milliseconds-and-timezone-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like timestamp in miliseconds

try

```
as.POSIXct( 13132800000/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC" )
[1] "1970-06-02 UTC"
```